# cellForItemAt IndexPath does not call if I'm using UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout. Is it a bug of iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

`cellForItemAt indexPath` does not call if I'm using `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.

In this case:

```
class Something: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

}
```

it calls my `cellforItemAtIndexPath`, but does not call my

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
}
```

but if I include `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`:

```
class Something: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
}
```

it will call:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
}
```

but will not call `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. I do not understand the problem. Is that a bug of iOS or I do not see anything?

Comment: Your class does not conform to the `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` although the functions should still get called. Additionally your `cellForRow` won't get called if your `numberOfItems` returns 0.

Comment: try class Something: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource.

Comment: I already use them, I just did not include them to make my code look short :) @RamkrishnaSharma

Comment: @Rikh If it does not conform to DataSource why then it shows when I remove `FlowDelegate` line??? And no, numberOfRows != 0 in my case

Comment: Thats why i said *functions should still get called* :), but never hurts to be sure!

Comment: Try this..Go to Attributes Inspector -> View Controller / Layout section -> Uncheck the "Adjust Scroll View Insets"

Comment: Also make sure your item height (size) is appropiate.

Answer (score 7):

For me, when creating the `collectionView` with layout, it should be `let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()`, not `let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()` which is so easy to neglect. I was trapped in this like more than twice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
import UIKit

let kSCREENWIDTH = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
let kSCREENHEIGHT = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

let COLLECTION_CELL = "collectionCell"

class DemoController: UIViewController {

    var collectionView : UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupCollectionView()
    }

   /// create programatically collection view
   fileprivate func setupCollectionView() {

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
//        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width:(kSCREENWIDTH-20)/2,height:150)
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 7, 5, 7)
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1

        collectionView = UICollectionView.init(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.view .addSubview(collectionView)

        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: COLLECTION_CELL)
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}


//MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate

extension DemoController : UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            // add your code here
    }

}

//MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
extension DemoController : UICollectionViewDataSource {


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        /// add your code here

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: COLLECTION_CELL, for: indexPath)

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

        print("Here cellForItemAt Works")

        return cell
    }


}

//MARK: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension DemoController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        print("Here sizeForItemAt Works")

        return CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
    }

}
```

Comment: Works for me is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case contentInset was not proper for the UICollectionView sub class.
Try adding below code in you sub class

```swift
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

override func reloadData() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        super.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Returning a size of `CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)` caused the delegate `cellForItemAt` not to get called in my case.

For example:

This would result in the issue.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
     return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
}
```

Where as this would not.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
     return CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
}
```